# Grails many-to-many and one-to-one with belongsTo

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm, belongs-to

I'm trying to achieve the following with Grails / Gorm:

Some users are lecturers. Several users can be assistants for several lecturers and several lecturers can have several assistants.

I'm trying to add an additional **many-to-many** relation to the existing **one-to-one** relation between User and Lecturer but **keep the belongsTo**.

This is what I had before:

```
class User {
   ...    
   Lecturer lecturer
}

class Lecturer {
   ...
   static belongsTo = [user:User]
}
```

Then I added the many-to-many relationship:

```
class User {
   ...
   Lecturer lecturer
   static hasMany = [lecturers: Lecturer]
}

class Lecturer {    
   static belongsTo = [user:User, assistants:User]
   static hasMany = [assistants: User]    
}
```

I get three tables:

user:

```
------------------------------
| id | .. | lecturer_id | .. |
------------------------------
```

lecturer:

```
-----------
| id | .. |
-----------
```

user_lecturer:

```
-----------------------------------
| user_lecturers_id | lecturer_id |
-----------------------------------
```

When I now call lecturer.assistants on a Lecturer without an assistant, I will get one user. This is not correct, because the table is empty. So, I guess the relation is interpreted as one-to-many and is giving me the user where the lecturer_id matches.

What will do the trick? (mappedBy ?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `call lecturer.assistants on a Lecturer without an assistant,` the bit you seem to suggest you are trying you haven't included. What does the query look like ? I know using HQL you can declare where left join is not null and achieve correct results

Comment: if a user `can be` a lecturer, you should use inheritance instead

Comment: @injecteer Actually a good idea. But I would rather keep them seperated. Does somebody know how to achieve a many-to-many relation and a one-to-one at once?

Comment: @injecteer I gave inheritance a chance. It actually works much better than I expected. The downside is the refactoring I'll have to do now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @H3ADLESS glad to help